# trying to figure out what is wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

```
REM Query 8
SELECT Make, Model, Engine, Transmission
FROM Auto
WHERE Upper(Make) = IN (‘FORD’, HONDA’, ‘NISSAN’, ‘SATURN’)
ORDER BY Make;
```

ERROR at line 3:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: remove the equal sign before 'IN'?

Comment: Are you sure you want an equals sign before `IN`?

Comment: Your apostrophes aren't actually apostrophes as well...

Answer (score 6):

You have two issues that I see:

1. You have an `=` before IN
2. your apostrophe characters are wrong

   ```
   SELECT Make, Model, Engine, Transmission
   FROM Auto
   WHERE Upper(Make) IN ('FORD', 'HONDA', 'NISSAN', 'SATURN')
   ORDER BY Make;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
REM Query 8
SELECT Make, Model, Engine, Transmission
FROM Auto
WHERE Upper(Make) IN ('FORD', 'HONDA', 'NISSAN', 'SATURN')
ORDER BY Make;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make the syntax correction as below

```
SELECT Make, Model, Engine, Transmission
FROM Auto
WHERE Upper(Make) IN (‘FORD’, HONDA’, ‘NISSAN’, ‘SATURN’)
ORDER BY Make;
```